# <replace> of “literate” option still on in tcblisting environment of tcolorbox

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I set `@` and `|` as `<replace>` of the `literate` option(from the package `listings`), and use it in `tcblisting`(from `tocolorbox`).

They work all right except that in the `text` part of `tcblisting`, `@` and `|` are still in their positions. They are not replaced as expected.

So, how to remove them?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing options={%
      literate={@}{{\color{red}}}0{|}{{\normalcolor}}0}
    }
rule@\rule{5pt}{5pt}|>rule
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: @ egreg. I have added a picture to explain my intention.

Comment: By default (set by `listing and text`), `tcblisting` env content is typeset as a listing in the upper part and typeset normally in the lower part. `listing options` only influence the upper, listing output so what you get in the lower part is just expected.

Comment: Thank you @muzimuzhi Z for your explanation that make me understand the reason. Still, is there a way to deal with this problem?

Comment: What do you expect in the lower part, "rule" + <a red square> + ">rule"?

Comment: @muzimuzhi Z Yes. as my attached pichture shows.

Comment: The attached picture shows "rule"+black square+">rule", so not a red square but a black one. I guess the black square is desired?

Comment: Sorry, I put things mess. The black square comes from the expanded result of `\rule{5pt}{5pt}`, this is what I want, What I don't want is `@` and `|` in the lower part of the tcolorbox. So, "rule"+black square+">rule" is just the typeset I want.